# VS2008 .NET3.5 Setup project unable to add exe or dll from VS2012 / .NET4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, setup-project

We have an older Windows application developed using **VS2008 .NET3.5**.

We have a new 3rd party "tool" application comprising an exe and dll developed using **VS2012 and .NET4.0**.

The intention is to have the older application deploy this 3rd party tool in a subfolder of its *Application Folder*. We already deploy a separate VS2010 .NET3.5 3rd party tool in this way. Therefore, I do know that adding 3rd party dlls and exes to the *Setup* project is normal practice.

**The Problem:**

I cannot add these new files to the *Setup* project.

From my VS2008 Solution's *Setup* project. I select the *File System Editor* and create the appropriate sub folder under the *Application Folder*. I then attempt to add the 3rd party VS2012 .NET4.0 dll and exe files by right-clicking to bring up the appropriate context menu, where I can try to ***Add*** either ***File ...*** or ***Assembly...***. All I get is the dialog: "The operation could not be completed".

I've tried Running as Administrator and also on a collegaue's PC. Same result.

Trawling the web suggests that, in principle, there should be no problem. I think the difficulty is that VS2008 is trying to be too clever by not treating these as anonymous files.

Causes, thoughts and solutions?

**Additional:**

I have even tried deploying these files as content. The installer now builds but silently ignores them.

Comment: You are probably right about the "too clever" guess.  You are digging yourself a pretty deep hole by having a dependency on multiple .NET versions.  I'm guessing that it dies when it recognizes the .NET 4 executables but then falls over when it checks them for dependencies because VS2008 doesn't know anything about the .NET 4 assembly metadata format.  Good odds that you'll need to create the installer in VS2010 or make a separate installer for the .NET 4 app to get ahead.

Comment: I agree Hans. I'm not going to find a solution with VS2008.I will need to look elsewhere. Many thanks for replying.